# Is isotope dating falsifiable?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics

I'd like to ask if the dating " saying something has existed for XXXX years " is scientific ?

When i try to apply the criterion of being falsifiable i find that the dating fails to satisfy that condition , since anything i will say can't be falsified by experiments  for example if i said the universe has existed for billion years while you said two billions years ? we can't run an experiment to know who is right? one may argue that the consequences of your models can be observed but what if the two models can contain the observations ? my point is how to know if the dating is right or wrong while it is impossible to run the events from the past.

Comment: [K-Ar dating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Ar_dating) is a very well-understood technique.  I don't understand why you're characterizing it as unscientific.

Comment: I mean how you know if it is valid in the past while you can't simulate the past events , idk how you know if it good technique if you can't test it in the past and you did not answer how to make it falsifiable ?

Comment: We've got no evidence the K-40 decay rate changes over time, and if it did change, that would be significantly at odds with established physics and nuclear chemistry.  I have a question for you: How do you measure the length of an object?  You put a ruler next to it and count hash marks.  But how do you know the ruler didn't magically change since the last time you picked it up?

Comment: You say it's not falsifiable but that depends on how specific you are about what you are testing. As you say, we can't actually test things like K-Ar dating. However, we **can** test stuff like C-14 dates. We have calibrated C-14 dates against fixed calendars like tree rings.

Answer (score 4):

Let's ask a different question: how do you know you're not twenty minutes old?  That is, "you" didn't actually write the question, you just *think* you did because things were different in the past such that, well, somehow or other you exist now and have memories of writing a post, but there are parameters which changed and somehow spoiled stuff.

Pretty silly, right?  But, frustrating, you can't completely rule this out with logic or science or anything else.  It's just a variant of [Descartes' evil demon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_demon), albeit possibly a non-intelligent demon (maybe there's just some process that generates pretend histories, and a flag flipped saying, "okay, stop generating pretend histories now, plug them into beings and start doing stuff for real").

So if you really want to know *absolutely for sure*, it is logically possible that we could be almost arbitrarily badly confused about almost everything.  This does an absolutely *terrible* job of explaining all the regularities we see, but it can't *completely* be ruled out.

But if you're "just" doing science, you don't need absolute certainty.  You ask: can we construct hypotheses that make predictions about what we observe, and do those hypotheses work on both observations we've already made and ones we haven't made yet?  Can we find better hypotheses?

And here, of *course* we can do science on stuff that's already past because it doesn't matter why you failed to make the observation before.  It doesn't need to have not happened; you just need to have not cheated by plugging the answer into the hypothesis before "testing" it.  You could get new observations by making new things happen, or looking at consequences of what has happened previously.  Doesn't matter *at all*, as long as it's honestly independent from the generation of the hypothesis.

Then the question is whether parameters can change in the past in a way that will confuse us.  Possibly!  The length of the day has, we think, changed throughout Earth's history.  Based on physical effects we can observe now, it looks like the rotation of the earth is slowing slightly, and [if we extrapolate](http://essayweb.net/physics/mathematica/daylength/Earth%20Rotation%20over%20Geologic%20Time.html) the day should have been about 22 hours long during the Cambrian.  If we check, by [measuring relative changes in sedimentary patterns](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000RvGeo..38...37W) that occur on yearly, daily, and lunar-monthly cycles, it seems pretty much spot-on.

Now, note what we did: we took multiple *different* predictions and they agreed with each other.  We didn't take *one* and trust it, we *checked*.  If some parameter changed in the past, it would somehow have to have affected these different factors by the same amount, so that they'd agree.

Dating via radioisotopes is done much the same way.  There are all sorts of radiogenic decay processes (for over a dozen, see *Radiogenic Isotope Geology* by Alan P. Dickin, Cambridge University Press (1995)) that agree with each other.  So any "parameter change" would have to affect *all* radioactive decay the same way.  Since decay of U235 and U238 is responsible for much of the internal heating of earth, if it had happened much much faster, the earth would have been a sphere of boiling lava unless thermal conductivity were also different.  (And the sun wouldn't work properly either.)  Furthermore, these methods agree with completely non-radioactive methods of relative time such as sediment accumulation, coral reef growth, sea-floor spreading, and so on.  So not only can we perform scientific studies in the past, when it comes specifically to radioisotope dating, we can check and cross-check and cross-cross-check, and everything checks out.  (*To be perfectly clear: these are tests of the hypothesis!*)  Now, all measurements have some associated error, so if you want to tell to 0.1% how old something is, it can be quite a challenge.  But if you want to tell if something is 5 million or 500 million years old it's really easy, and really robust (if you follow proper procedures and measure or avoid sources of error, as you will if you e.g. read *Radiogenic Isotope Geology*).

So, in conclusion: while it is logically possible for evil demons to trick us, or for multiple models to give similar answers, in practice with radioisotope dating there are no competing models which make any sense at all, and tons of hypothesis-testing has been performed and the standard hypothesis has done really, really well.

Comment: But if i can't prove that i have existed for twenty minutes through science , it is ok with me because i see science as not the source of knowledge only so i do not expect science to prove everything and it must have strict conditions , other question , if someone said i will only believe in experiments in science and not from any inductive statement about the past , Do you know a school that hold that thinking ? am i against science if i did so ?

Comment: @MohamedOsama - Science doesn't _prove_ anything. (But neither does essentially anything else: see Descartes' evil demon.) Whether or not you're against _science_ if you say it can't tell you about the past, you're certainly against _logic_. Science just formalizes the process of coming to know things, and at any instant, science is _always_ about stuff in the past even if you plan to do more experiments in the future. Also, science doesn't care what is OK with you and what is not. It's not like it'll say, "Ungrateful person!  You don't believe in me!  No iPhone for you!"

Comment: But maybe i have different difinition for science than for you , that's why i asked you about a school holding that definition

Comment: @MohamedOsama - I am not aware of any significant school of thought among either philosophers of science or practicing scientists that holds that science is limited in the way you suggest, probably because, as I explained, it's illogical to hold such a view.  In particular, the Popperian view is generally the most _conservative_ in what it calls science, and it easily admits scientific examination of certain kinds of historical events (including dating things).

Answer (score 3):

There are many things that are unclear or uncertain in this question. What does it mean to be "scientific?" Since you use the phrase *falsifiable*, I will assume you refer to the idea of science as put forward by [Karl Popper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper). In particular, the scientific method is about testing ideas through empirical falsifiability. A theory cannot be proven right, but it can be falsified.

In this context, the act of declaring any one thing or another is not the pertinent question. You ask if "saying something has existed" is falsifiable. This is broad and depends on many things. Let's say I claim that *I have existed for 200 years.* To better ignore metaphysical questions about what it means to exist, let's rephrase this as *I have been alive for 200 years.* Sure, this is a lousy theory. My parents and governmental records could easily say that I wasn't. In that sense, it is falsifiable - but it's mostly an uninteresting theory. Whether or not one calls it scientific, it is utterly irrelevant.

But it may be that you are asking about whether the actual techniques that scientists use to date events in the past are scientific. And here, the answer is yes.

There are very many interrelated theories about dating. Some can be found on the Wikipedia page [Absolute Dating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_dating). The important aspect is that we have theories involving dating from carbon-14, or potassium-argon, or argon-argon, or thermoluminescence, or relatively simpler tasks like counting tree rings or cross-examining found fossils or the like. The Earth's magnetic field changes from time to time, and we believe we understand how this affects rocks. So some rocks can be roughly dated through [paleomagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleomagnetism). Or we can use [volcanic ash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tephrochronology).

We build up larger cohesive theories about dating from these smaller, individual theories. Counting tree rings is a particularly easy to imagine theory with clear testing mechanisms. Grow some trees, take core samples, and count the rings. We can get a little more involved by noting that particularly large rings occur during seasons of particularly favorable weather. Matching these up across many trees (and fossilized or otherwise preserved trees from the past) might allow one to get even deeper. Now someone might come along and start to compare carbon-14 dating to tree ring dating. If there was disagreement, then something is wrong. Ideas must be adjusted or thrown away.

And so it goes, each part tested and honed against each other. I haven't even mentioned that each technique is interrelated with areas of science. Nuclear physicists and geologists have a lot to say about the science going into their respective techniques. The fact that we now have a rather large and interconnected set of resources for dating suggests that dating is highly scientific.

As a final reference, you might consider reading about the [Problem of induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction), which is a related concern.

Comment: Let me tell you what i understand from a thing being falsifiable and scientific : is that the experiments must be done on it and the results are ok , you said we tested the Dating in our time and hence it works , but maybe there were effects which distorts the results of dating?

Comment: Another question , if someone said i will only believe in experiments in science and not from any inductive statement about the past , Do you know a school that hold that thinking ?

Comment: @MohamedOsama "there were effects which distorts the results of dating" -- that's why different methods are used and validated against each other. If these effects were real, it'd mean most of the involved branches of knowledge would have to revise their foundations. It is not impossible, but highly unlikely. As for not believing in inductive statements about the past, wouldn't that exclude the same experiments you mentioned, since they happened in the past too? If this school of thought would hold that the past could have been an exception to the rule, where's the limit? Was it yesterday?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple important points:

First, you are right when you say that we can't use an experiment to see how old this universe is, but I think that misses the point, because we can run experiments on the *consequences of that event* instead, and falsify hypotheses of the universe backwards from that.

Second, we know that to run such experiments or to deduce logically from them the consequences of those experiments makes sense because matter is intelligible. Matter isn't magical. It doesn't behave unpredictably. It is governed by rules. Many philosophers throughout the ages have held this. In terms of contemporary thinkers, you can see this idea in works as diverse as those of Richard Dawkins and of Pope Benedict.

Comment: The problem is alot of theories can contain the results ? how you will judge then ? i did not say magic occurs i simply mean i do not know maybe there is some parameters that affected the carbon

Answer (score 2):

This is a bizarre contention.  Experiments do not have to be things we contrive in a lab.  They just have to be predictions of measures not yet taken.  When we looked at Mercury coming around the Sun and found what General Relativity predicted, that was an opportunity for the theory to be falsified.  We do not have to create the Sun and Mercury from scratch to call that an experiment, we just have to do something we have not done before about which the theory makes new and specific predictions.

Noting that living things continually take in carbon affected by radiation, and that once dead they stop doing so, and noting that carbon becomes less radioactive over time at a given rate, I can run an experiment that measures the radioactive content in a fiber.

If I am guessing the fiber is X years old, and there is more radioactivity than those observations would indicate, my guess is falsified, or the entire notion of carbon-dating, and thus all of nuclear physics is falsified.

Every other form of dating has the same construction.  Knowing X process happens Y fast, I expect it to be a degree Y * A complete after A years, and if I guess something is A years old and find the process is less complete than expected, the guess is falsified or the whole theory that supports the measured speed of the process is falsified.

Either way, dating is one of the things most consistently done in science in a falsifiable manner.

Comment: But the problem is you connected the results in the future with the past? maybe there are parameters which simply spoiled the dating results

Comment: @MohamedOsama That falls into the case of 'ceteris paribus'.  Every evaluation can be wrong for unforeseen reasons. That is why good scientists use p-values.

Comment: What is p value ?

Comment: A p-value is the statistic that indicates how likely you are to be wrong, more properly, it is the percentage of those repeating your experiment who can expect to get contradictory results if the model is actually good.  In general scientists allow for a 5% chance of failure, and they expect others to be able to repeat similar experiments, and fail 5% of the time.  Choosing the rate of failure and handling it responsibly whenever the statistics are strong enough for you to compute it, acknowledges that control is limited --  that stuff goes wrong in experiments and they should be re-checked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-philosophical answer, which I believe dodges many of the more quirky issues associated with the question "what is scientific."  Instead, it is a linguistic one.

The vast majority of science is backed by statistical rigor.  Scientists talk of dating because the techniques used in dating have been backed scientifically using statistics.  There are plenty of questions about whether those dating schemes are valid, but they have at least chosen to expose themselves to the brutality of statistics: if the statistics start to suggest the hypothesis is false, people will abandon the hypothesis.

A single measurement, however, cannot claim such statistical rigor.  Even multiple consistent measurements by the same or related techniques may not be sufficient to claim statistical rigor.  However, what can be claimed is that the method has been tested statistically.

I think that if you treat "saying something is XXX years is scientific" as though it had been "saying something has been measured at XXX years old using scientifically rigorous techniques" might have been more what was intended by the statement in the first place.  This wording recognizes an individual measurement of age as a process with error, but argues that the error is bound by the methodology.

Comment: Is this approach described/based on published work?

Comment: Yes and no.  No, I did not draw it directly from a published work. It is a natural result of statistics.  My terminology may be flawed, because I come from a simulation background not a philosophical one, but in our terms, this is called "drawing" from a random variable.  You can draw a "heads" from a coin toss, and it says nothing about the statistical behavior of a coin.  It is the predictive part of science which extends science out from the realm of cheap-to-repeat experiments into the real world of engineering.

Comment: Individual measurements can, nonetheless, invalidate hypotheses.  For example, "all crows are black" is a hypothesis; upon seeing a white crow, you reject the "all crows are black" hypothesis.  No statistics needed.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Yes they, can as long as you use logical terms like "all" or "none" and don't have any statistical behaviors built into the model.  once you get into hypotheses phrased statistically (which all dating methods that I know of are), a single data point cannot invalidate the hypothesis.  At worst it can draw a great deal of negative attention to the hypothesis.

Comment: @CortAmmon - If the data point is believed to be uncorrupted, a single data point _can_ invalidate the hypothesis.  It might be relatively easily rescued ("this distribution isn't Gaussian after all"), but you don't expect single data points with p < 1e-40, for instance.  If you get something like that, your hypothesis is somehow wrong.  (At least the way you modeled the statistics for that hypothesis is wrong.)

Comment: @Rex Kerr it can only be invalidated non-statistically, as we have no method of determining the structure of a random variable from a data point besides the obvious existence statement that that datapoint had a non-zero chance of occurring.  Whether that qualifies as "invalidation" or not depends on a personal definition of what "invalidate" means.

Comment: If you come up with "hypothesis invalid because it is inconsistent with expected variation, p < 1e-40", _why does it matter how many data points went into the calculation, as long as the calculation is right_?

Comment: @RexKerr  Because I can dye a crow black, just to mess with you.  If you ever actually get p < 1e-40 from a single measure you probably did your math wrong.

Comment: @jobermark - It's just as likely that the statistical model in the hypothesis is wrong.  Normal distributions are popular because they have nice mathematical properties, not because data actually follows them all that often.  Sometimes it's important to know if they're not, and it's not that many standard deviations to 1e-40.

Comment: @RexKerr That is the biggest part of your math.  You never know the *real* distribution you are drawing from, so unless both the source of the statistics and the sample are both large enough for the Law of Large Numbers, you cannot really trust normal statistics to give you a p-value.  In that sense, it *really does matter* how many data points you used.  Normal distributions are used because the sum of enough of **any** continuous distribution is normal, so all samples expect normality with enough data points, not because of the nice math,

Comment: @RexKerr The only notable exceptions are places where a real mathematical model predicts the actual distribution.  But that is rare, outside of physics and infomation theory.  It is easier to get more points and let the LLN apply than to wrangle all of your potential causes into a mathematically definitive computation of a distribution.

Comment: To the point that a single dating presumes a distribution, the OP actually has a point, if a very weak one.  Officiously, only populations have distributions, not individual events.  So falsification based on a single sample really is unlikely to ever be meaningful.  Like I said, I can dye a swan (bleach a crow?) or someone can walk by with a magnet that affects your equipment, etc.  That is one reason experiments need to be repeated.

Comment: @jobermark - The law of large numbers only applies if you take the sum (or equivalent). That this is true in any particular case is usually taken more on faith than first principles (except in physics). People love to say that human height is Normal. The standard deviation is around 7 cm for men: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9730. With about ten billion people, this means that the tails should be around 42 cm off the mean. Sultan Kosen is 251 cm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultan_K%C3%B6sen), at least 70 cm taller (p<1e-23).  Odds in population, p<1e-13.  Hypothesis is wrong.

Comment: Yes.  That is just an example of **exactly what I said**.  You can almost never assume normality unless you have **many data points** to average or otherwise combine.  You asked **why it matters how many data points you have**  That is why.  If you have one data point, you should not do important statistics on it unless you have a **very strong** reason to assume you know the exact distribution.

Comment: @RexKerr To go a bit wide of the topic: That hypothesis does not need to be disproven, it is illogical on its face.  It always amuses me when people assume things like height are normally distributed, because it is a two-tailed distribution.  OK, so I can imagine Paul Bunyan, as the most extreme sort of outlier.  But if you claim height is normal, you theorize a definite probability of humans of negative height!

Comment: @jobermark - We have close to billions of data points on human height.  Just because I highlighted one outlier to reject a somewhat implausible hypothesis (but of the form that is made surprisingly often, at least implicitly in statistical tests of other hypotheses) doesn't mean that the data is scanty.  Also, the probability of negative height is so low it is utterly negligible.  But I do agree that the wise experimenter will not assume a distribution unless they have very good reason to know what it is.  (Alas, not all experimentalists are wise in this way.)